# I need to export a distance matrix in its triangular form to a .txt or a .csv file

Tags: r, matrix, export, distance, triangular

So far I've tried all what I have found in internet.
I have a distance matrix (dist class) and all the elements I've learned to "coerce" the matrix have not been effective. 
I want to keep the triangular form.

Does any one already know how to export a dist matrix?
f

Comment: I've been poorly qualified since I asked the same question. But, I found the answer I needed, at last!
So, I want to know, if any of the qualifiers tried and worked for them the supposed answers there have been already written.

Comment: I know this is an older question, but the people who originally answered said it was a duplicate question when it wasn't. The question that they are referring to pertains to exporting the distance matrix in non-triangular format, when this one pertains to exporting the matrix in triangular format. Another answer to this question would be:

Comment: sink("distance_matrixt.txt")
       print(distance_matrix)
       sink()

Answer (score 1):

One option is to set a new matrix from your `dist` matrix and then replace the upper triangular part with `""`. Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10, 5, 1), y = rnorm(10))
mat <- dist(df, diag = TRUE, upper = FALSE)
mat2 <- as.matrix(mat)
mat2[upper.tri(mat2, diag = FALSE)] <- ""
write.csv(mat2, "mat2.csv")
```

PS: the consequence of that procedure is that your matrix is now a character matrix. So, do not forget to change the class of its components before using them.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you very very much!!!!!!!!!! Finally an answer that works!